# Identify who invokes Event Handler

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, event-handling, windows-ce

I have my app with my labels written to centralize when its text was modified.

To make that I invoke a method through an EventHandler. I want to use same method to each one of my labels, but I don´t know how to identify in the method which label invoke it.

If I have a code like this:

```
       lbl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ..code..
           label1.Location = new Point("label's location");
           ..more code..
        }
```

and I invoke again that method from another label, how could I modify that code in order to know which label invoke it?

**SOLUTION** Thanks for the help, This is the first time I tried to make something with the event handler and didn't know that I need to cast the sender. That solves my problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506815/how-do-i-identify-which-control-generated-the-click-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sender` object in the event handler signature is the control that raised the event.

Simply cast this object and you have access to all the control's information.

```
Label label = sender as Label;
```

You do need to be a little bit careful with this, since you are assuming that only controls of type `Label` are raising events that have this handler method.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `sender` is for:

```
Point p = ((Label)sender).Location;
// adjust p 
label1.Location = p;
```